# Kinematic equations using Universal Gravitation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

This has been asked on here [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967496/how-to-integrate-gravitational-force), but the question was never fully answered. After reading through the math, I get stuck at what seems like a dead end.

This is what I have so far:

The gravitational force is given by

$$F = \dfrac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

and if you divide force by mass to get acceleration you have

$$a = \dfrac{Gm}{r^2}$$

to find velocity, you have to integrate acceleration with respect to time. Unfortunately, the equation is a function of position, which is itself a function of time. In order to integrate, you have to multiply both sides of the equation by velocity to cancel out ${\mathrm{d}t}$.

$$V^2 = Gm\int \dfrac{1}{r^2} \,\mathrm{d}t \dfrac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

I solved this equation and got

$$V = \pm \sqrt{c-\frac{Gm}{r}}$$

From here I tried to integrate again to get position, multiplying both sides to get ${\mathrm{d}r}$ by itself.

$$RV = \int \sqrt{c-\frac{Gm}{r}}\, \mathrm{d}t \dfrac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

After that, I was planning to divide the equation I got by velocity, in order to get the equation for R. But before I could do that I realized that I had a couple of problems. For starters, if I integrated my equation for velocity with respect to position, I would have a function for position which takes itself as an input. And besides that, When I tried to integrate I got a very convoluted function with imaginary numbers, which doesn't really make sense in the context of kinematics.

So I was hoping that somebody here would be able to tell me where I went wrong solving this.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation#Classical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

**velocity v(r)**

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{G\,m}{r^2}\\
\frac{v\,dv}{dt}=-\frac{G\,m}{r^2}\frac{dr}{dt}\quad\Rightarrow\\
\int v\,dv=-\int \frac{G\,m}{r^2}\,dr\\
\frac{v^2}{2}=\frac{G\,m}{r}\\
v(r)=\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{\frac{G\,m}{r}}$$

**position r(t)**

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=v(r)=\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{\frac{G\,m}{r}}\quad \Rightarrow\\
dr\,\sqrt{r}=\sqrt{2\,G\,m}\,\,dt\\
\int dr\,\sqrt{r}=\int \sqrt{2\,G\,m}\,\,dt\\
\frac{2}{3}\,r^{3/2}=\sqrt{2\,G\,m}\,t\\
r(t)=\left(\frac{3}{2}\,\sqrt{2\,G\,m}\,t\right)^{2/3}+r_0$$

$$v(t)=v(r(t))$$

Comment: What happened to the integration constants?

Comment: $ r_0$ is the integration constant

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but since V(r) is a square root function, how do you know if it is going in the positive or negative direction?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can write $a=v\frac{dv}{dx}$, which will make things easier:

$$vdv=-\frac{Gm}{x^2}dx$$
$$\int_0^{\Delta v}vdv=-\int_\infty^x \frac{Gm}{x^2}dx$$
$$\Delta v(x)=\sqrt\frac{2Gm}{x}$$
$$\sqrt x\,dx=\sqrt {2Gm}\,dt$$
$$\int_\infty^x\sqrt x\,dx=\int_0^t \sqrt {2Gm}\,dt$$
$$\frac{9}{8}x^3(t)=Gmt^2$$

Note that last equation is actually Kepler's third law!

Hope it helps!